# haskell - generate an instance for all classes except one specific type

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

Is it possible to do something like

```
class T a
class U a
instance U ()
instance ( NOT U a ) => T a
```

Context: I am trying to write a function that takes [HLists](http://web.archive.org/web/20120816053543/http://homepages.cwi.nl/~ralf/HList/) and removes elements of a certain type (here the unit type).

I feel like there might be some issue with the open world assumption, but even being able to do it in a hardcoded manner (instead of NOT U a , something like NOT a~()) should seem possible.

edit: As pointed out in a comment by C.A. McMann, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6942637/157360) question is pretty much an exact duplicate of mine. If a moderator feels like closing this, feel free to.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure this is really a duplicate--the means of constructing the "not this type" constraint is the same, but the use (context of an instance vs. function) is different and given the complications involved in instance resolution I don't think it's entirely obvious that my answer to the other question would cover this one. That's why I linked to the other question in a comment, rather than voting to close this one myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it using a trick of Oleg's, which even has its own library [on hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-equality-check)

By heavily abusing the type class system, it is possible to generate a fundep

```
class TypeEq a b result | a b -> result
```

such that `TypeEq a b True` only when `a~b`, and `TypeEq a b False` otherwise

so you can write

```
instance (TypeEq () a False) => T a
```

and I think that should work.  I should be clear, this type equality test is pure evil in how it is implemented, but it does mostly work.  Check out the code for that library if you want to understand how this works/generalize it (also read the HList paper).

If it is at all possible to do what you want to do without negative constraint, do that instead.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. I'll look at the code for this. I actually read some of the HList paper, but I didn't really see what I was looking for.