# Error while trying to use type families to dissambiguate overlapping instances with flexible contexts

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-families

I'm trying to define instances for typeclasses using some fairly complex conditions on the type arguments of the type I'm working with, and thought that a useful approach would be to declare a closed type family that chooses between the instances I'm defining.  Unfortunately, I can't get that idea to work at all, as GHC complains that the instances are duplicates.  Here's a  simplified example that gives the same error I'm seeing:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, TypeFamilies #-}
data MyContainer a = NoValue | OneValue a | TwoValues a a

data Yes
data No

type family IsInt t where
    IsInt Int = Yes
    IsInt a   = No

instance IsInt t ~ Yes => Show (MyContainer t) where
    show _ = "Type is int"
instance IsInt t ~ No => Show (MyContainer t) where
    show _ = "Type is not int"
```

The error I'm seeing is:

```
src/Test.hs:11:10:
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance (IsInt t ~ Yes) => Show (MyContainer t)
        -- Defined at src/Test.hs:11:10
      instance (IsInt t ~ No) => Show (MyContainer t)
        -- Defined at src/Test.hs:13:10
```

How can I disambiguate these instances (without resorting to overlapping instances, which work for this test code but don't seem to be working correctly for my more complex original code)?

Answer (score 5):

You need to work with an auxiliary class. Enable `ScopedTypeVariables`, `MultiParamTypeClasses`, `UndecidableInstances`, and so on. Code not tested yet.

```
class Showy status t where
  showy :: proxy status -> t -> String

instance Showy Yes t where
  showy _ _ = "yup"

instance Showy No t where
  showy _ _ = "nope"

newtype S t = S t
--Avoid overlapping unrelated `Show` instances.
--This newtype would be unnecessary for a custom
--class or when you're making instances for a
--parameterized type already.

instance (IsInt t ~ status, Showy status t) => Show (S t)
  show (S t) = showy (Proxy :: Proxy status) t
```

Note that you can also make use of the `Int` if you like, by replacing the `Yes` instance with something like

```
instance t ~ Int => Showy Yes t where
  showy _ x = show (x + 22)
```

You can also constrain the `No` instance if you wish:

```
instance Enum t => Showy No t where
  showy _ = show . fromEnum
```

Comment: Note that the `Show t` instance will overlap with all the standard ones.

Comment: @chi, I fixed that.